# Changing web.config programmatically: section "buildProviders"

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config

For deployment, I wrote a tool that modifies some **web.config** settings from development to production environments. That works well except in one case:

When I try to set **debug** to **false**, my **buildProviders** section disappears.

This is my **system.web** section:

```html
  <system.web>
    <machineKey ... />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".resx"/>
        <remove extension=".resources"/>
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
            ...
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

and this is my modification code:

```
    private void ChangeDebugSetting()
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection comp = (System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/compilation");
        comp.Debug = false;
        configuration.Save();
    }
```

In the resulting web.config the **buildProviders** section is missing.

In the debugger I can see that the **comp.BuildProviders** collection is empty. However, a protected property **base.Items** contains two elements with *_entryType = Removed* and *_key = ".resx"* resp. *_key = ".resources"*.

How can I manage that both "remove" elements will be saved to **web.config**?

Comment: Why do you don't use TransformXML task in the project file? Please see possible solution here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859 or use manual transformation here: http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Applying-MSBuild-Config-Transformations-to-any-config-file-without-using-any-Visual-Studio-extensions

Comment: The reason is that I already have a mechanism that modifies some web.config settings on run time via a special web page (e.g. switching on / off the ASP.Net trace). I thought I could also use this mechanism for switching debug on/off. (In some cases I would like to have line numbers in exception stack traces.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem using classes of the System.Xml Namespace (XmlDocument, XmlElement etc.) instead of thje System.Configuration namespace.

This works fine.